# python implementation of list append

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def my_append1(list1, item):
    list1 = list1 + [item]
    return

def my_append2(list1, item):
    list1 += [item]
    return
```

The above two functions give me different results:

```
test = [1, 2, 3]
my_append1(test, 1)
print(test) ==> [1, 2, 3]

test = [1, 2, 3]
my_append2(test, 1)
print(test) ==> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Why are they different?

Comment: `+=`'s analogue is `extend`, not `append`

Comment: Using `+=` is equivalent to `list1.extend([item])`, using `list1 = list1 + [item]` is just rebinding `list1` inside of `my_append1` to a brand new list object in the local scope, which gets thrown away when the function exists.